# php mail syntax error

Tags: php, html, email

```
$mail_body = '<html>
<body style="background-color:#CCC; color:#000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:1.8em;">
<h3><a href="http://www.grillontherock.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/OODKT9h.png" alt="GR" width="194" height="123" border="0"></a> 
</h3>
<p>Hello ' . $name . ',</p>
<p>You can make this out to be just like most any web page or design format you require using HTML and CSS.</p>
<p>Grill on the Rock </p>
<hr>
<p>To opt out of receiving this newsletter,  <a href="http://grillontherock.x10host.com/email/optout.php?e=' . $email . '">click here</a> and we will remove you from the listing immediately.</p>
</body>
</html>';

        $to = "$email";
        $subject = "Example Grill on the Rock Email";
        $from="info@grillontherock.com";

        $mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, "From:".$from);

    }
    if($mail_result){
        echo "Email has been sent successfully";
    }
```

I am having problem with sending email with php and html.

This code works perfectly fine but the email I am getting is

[image]

but when I use double quotation for html file php code greys out for some reason.

```
$mail_body = "<html>
<body style="background-color:#CCC; color:#000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:1.8em;">
<h3><a href="http://www.grillontherock.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/OODKT9h.png" alt="GR" width="194" height="123" border="0"></a> 
</h3>
<p>Hello ' . $name . ',</p>
<p>You can make this out to be just like most any web page or design format you require using HTML and CSS.</p>
<p>Grill on the Rock </p>
<hr>
<p>To opt out of receiving this newsletter,  <a href="http://grillontherock.x10host.com/email/optout.php?e=' . $email . '">click here</a> and we will remove you from the listing immediately.</p>
</body>
</html>";

        $to = "$email";
        $subject = "Example Grill on the Rock Email";
        $from="info@grillontherock.com";

        $mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, "From:".$from);

    }
    if($mail_result){
        echo "Email has been sent successfully";
    }
```

a bit new to php and html and I could not find similar problem at the moment.

Also, Is it possible to have email as html form and bring that html through send php file?

Comment: Danny instead of attaching screenshot, add relevant code snippets. They will be more helpful to the community in order to help you.

Comment: Remove pic of code. Please use typed code for asking help.

Comment: put your code instead of screen shots danny..if some one wants to help he can at least try copying your code.....

Comment: oops sorry ill fix that right now

Comment: I think it has something to do with single and double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `Content-Type` to `text/html` in mail headers

Example headers with `Content Type`:

```
$headers = "From: danny@danny.domain\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: no-reply@danny.domain\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

then

```
$mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);
```

@edit.

Also check exaple #4 at:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: thanks so much for the help the extra link helped alot

Answer (score 0):

With second html you are having problem with double quotes, because you are using double quotes inside the html, try to escape them. Try this:

or try the link below:
[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Content-Type` to `text/html` in mail headers to send your mail as html mail.

Example headers:

```
$headers = "From: mymail@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: no-reply@mymail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

finally after your content you need to send mail like the following.

```
$mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);
```

Then for your double quotes problem : here you used double quotes inside double quotes. if that so you need to escape it with "/".